# Is facebook or twitter using JSONAPI specification, if not why?

Tags: json, json-api

I've came across JSONAPI specification standards, which I'm planning to use in further new product developments. I'm having this doubt as if major players use this specification in their products.

Is there any trade-off of using JSONAPI standards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So

1. Json api is new. Fb and twitter are over a decade old
2. Fb and twitter operate at a massive scale where anything they do is going to be different from your needs. In general, they're not good examples for what is best for you.
3. Take a look at https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/825
4. To decide whether to use it depends in whether you like it and can use ot build tooling that supports it